# $H_0(\iota):H_0(\mathbb{S^1})\to H_o(\mathbb{D}^2)$ is the zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am wondering why $H_0(\iota):H_0(\mathbb{S^1})\cong\mathbb{Z}\to H_o(\mathbb{D}^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero map. Here $\iota$ means the inclusion $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{D}^2$.

The map $\iota$ defines a chain map $$\iota_n: S_n(\mathbb{S}^1)\to S_n(\mathbb{D}^2),\quad \iota_n(\alpha:\Delta^n\to\mathbb{S}^1):=\iota\circ\alpha.$$

Now $H_n(\iota):H_n(\mathbb{S}^1)\to H_n(\mathbb{D}^2)$ is defined as $H_n(\iota)([c]):=[\iota_n (c)]$.

But what is the reason for $H_0(\iota)$ being zero?

Comment: I think you need to check your sources. That map is the identity, not the zero map.

Comment: To be more precise: it takes a generator for the first group to a generator for the second.

Comment: This is what I thought as well! :) But for $n=1$ this would be the zero map $\mathbb{Z}\to 0$, wouldn't it?

Comment: ^It better be....

Comment: What Randall said. But to be clear: you asked about $H_0$, not $H_1$, and it's generally considered a bit rude to shift your question after asking it. (This case is an exception: no one's written an "answer" yet. But someone might be crafting one right now, and resent the idea that their work is wasted because you decided to ask something else.) For this one, now that you know a little more, write up your own answer, and then accept it. That'll close the question. (Accepting your own answer gets you no points, so it's ok to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false.  Indeed, $H_0(S^1)$ is freely generated by $[\alpha]$ for any $\alpha:\Delta^0\to S^1$ and the analogous statement holds for $H_0(D^2)$.  Since $H_0(\iota)([\alpha])=[\iota\circ \alpha]$ for any such $\alpha$ and $\iota\circ \alpha$ is just a singular $0$-simplex in $D^2$, this means $H_0(\iota)$ maps a free generator of $H_0(S^1)$ to a free generator of $H_0(D^2)$, and hence is an isomorphism.